# Using automated default values with Filter Script in meshlabserver

Tags: meshlab

I want to use Filter Scripts to run Hausdorff Distance filter and Colorize by vertex quality.
When creating a *.mlx Filter Script from GUI MeshLab I get default calculated values for **SampleNum** and **MaxDist** in Hausdorff Distance Filter and **Max** value for Colorize filter.

Those are the *.mlx files:

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Remove Duplicate Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Hausdorff Distance">
  <Param value="0" tooltip="The mesh whose surface is sampled. For each sample we search the closest point on the Target Mesh." name="SampledMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Sampled Mesh"/>
  <Param value="1" tooltip="The mesh that is sampled for the comparison." name="TargetMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Target Mesh"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="Save the position and distance of all the used samples on both the two surfaces, creating two new layers with two point clouds representing the used samples." name="SaveSample" type="RichBool" description="Save Samples"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="For the search of maxima it is useful to sample vertices and edges of the mesh with a greater care. It is quite probably the the farthest points falls along edges or on mesh vertexes, and with uniform montecarlo sampling approachesthe probability of taking a sample over a vertex or an edge is theoretically null.&lt;br>On the other hand this kind of sampling could make the overall sampling distribution slightly biased and slightly affects the cumulative results." name="SampleVert" type="RichBool" description="Sample Vertexes"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleEdge" type="RichBool" description="Sample Edges"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleFauxEdge" type="RichBool" description="Sample FauxEdge"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleFace" type="RichBool" description="Sample Faces"/>
  <Param value="30514" tooltip="The desired number of samples. It can be smaller or larger than the mesh size, and according to the choosed sampling strategy it will try to adapt." name="SampleNum" type="RichInt" description="Number of samples"/>
  <Param min="0" value="233.888" tooltip="Sample points for which we do not find anything whithin this distance are rejected and not considered neither for averaging nor for max." name="MaxDist" type="RichAbsPerc" description="Max Distance" max="468.287"/>
 </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Colorize by vertex Quality">
  <Param value="0" tooltip="The value that will be mapped with the lower end of the scale (blue)" name="minVal" type="RichFloat" description="Min"/>
  <Param value="0.8" tooltip="The value that will be mapped with the upper end of the scale (red)" name="maxVal" type="RichFloat" description="Max"/>
  <Param min="0" value="0" tooltip="If not zero this value will be used for a percentile cropping of the quality values.&lt;br> If this parameter is set a value P to &lt;i>P&lt;/i> then the two values &lt;i>V_min,V_max&lt;/i> for which &lt;i>P&lt;/i>% of the vertices have a quality &lt;b>lower or greater than &lt;i>V_min,V_max&lt;/i> are used as min/max values for clamping.&lt;br>&lt;br> The automated percentile cropping is very useful for automatically discarding outliers." name="perc" type="RichDynamicFloat" description="Percentile Crop [0..100]" max="100"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="If true the min max range will be enlarged to be symmertic (so that green is always Zero)" name="zeroSym" type="RichBool" description="Zero Simmetric"/>
 </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

The problem is that I those values are calculated based on the specific mesh used to create the *.mlx file and I want to use it for a different set of meshes that those values are not suitable for them.

Is there a way to set the Filter Script to use the default values of the current model (as done in GUI - where it opens the dialog with the default values)?

If this is not possible, how can I calculate those 3 values per mesh?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When the `Hausdorff Distance` dialog appears in meshlab, and before you click on the `Apply`button, the program assigns some default values to parameters in the dialog.

[image: Hausdorff Distance Dialog]

- Number of samples, or **SampleNum**, is computed as the number of vertices of "Sampled mesh"
- Max Distance, or **MaxDist**, is computed as a 5% of the length of the Bounding Box Diagonal of "Sampled Mesh"

Those values are designed just to accelerate the calculus of the Distances, but you can put anything there. Just change your Hausdorff.mlx file to do `SampleNum=99999` and `MaxDist=9999` or any huge number and you'll get the same values.

For `Colorize by vertex Quality` filter, the **Max** is a number between 0.0 and 1.0 that will be multiplied by the greater value in the qualities to compute an upper clamp value for qualities. So `Max=1.0` should be a safe value for every mesh.

Off topic: I don't know if you are aware of [MLX (or MeshLabXML)](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML) project. This is a python library that helps you to write the .mlx files that can be executed by meshlabserver. This could help you to automatic creation of .mlx filters adapted to each pair of meshes.